# Define $F(x) = \int_{4}^{x^2}f(t)dt, 2 \leq x$. Prove that $F^{-1}(0)$ and $(F^{-1})'(0)$ exist and find their values.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, solution-verification

$f(x)$ is continuous, positive, and real and is such that $f(n) =1$ for all integers $n$. Define $F(x) = \int_{4}^{x^2}f(t)dt, 2 \leq x$. Prove that  $F^{-1}(0)$ and $(F^{-1})'(0)$ exist and find their values.

**My attempt**

Firstly, I will show that $F(x)$ is one to one. $F'(x) = 2xf(x^2)$. On the interval $[2,\infty)$ we  see that $F'(x) > 0$ (strictly increasing). By theorem, $F(x)$ must be $1-1$ on that domain and have a corresponding inverse.

Note that $F(2) = \int_{4}^{4}f(t)dt = 0$. This means that $F^{-1}(0) = 2$. Since the function has an inverse $$(F^{-1})'(0) = \frac{1}{F'(F^{-1}(0))} = \frac{1}{F'(2)} = \frac{1}{2 \times 2 \times f(4)} = \frac{1}{4}$$

Is this solution valid and justified?

Comment: Yes, it is valid and justified.